# .NET double rendered differently when shown in TextBox or Label (WPF)

Tags: .net, textbox, label, double, precision

When the least significant values of a double are non-zero, it gets rendered with different precision depending on which control is showing it.

In my case, I tried using a TextBox and a Label. ToString seems to give the same result than a TextBox. However, a Label control shows more precision.

Here's an example (just drag the thumb to see what I mean):

```
<Window x:Class="SliderTest.SliderTestWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="SliderTestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel>
    <Slider Name="slider" TickFrequency="0.1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Value</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Value</TextBlock>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Why is used a different way to render doubles in each control?

What can I do to render doubles in a Label just as they are rendered in a TextBox?

Answer (score 4):

You may provide a format string for the binding. A sample using a currency formatter is:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Double, StringFormat=F3}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Double, StringFormat=Amount: {0:C}}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Double, StringFormat=Amount: \{0:C\}}"/>
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Double" StringFormat="{}{0:C}"/>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Source:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx

String Format help:
http://alexonasp.net/samples/stringformatting/